# Update Text on a page weekly from a original file

Tags: web-part, page-layout

Here is what I need to do.
I need to update daily/weekly a text/news section on my page.  I want my assistant to modify a file (uploaded on Documents library) and pull that text to the page as a News information.
Any way to do it?

Reggie

Answer (score 1):

If it's SharePoint 2013 you can go to that file (ms office files) click on the elipses so you get the preview, at the bottom of the preview there is a drop down, click the drop down and select embed information. Copy the code and paste it in a content editor.